# MVC3 RedirectToAction Caching

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, http-caching, http-redirect

I have an MVC3 application. I have an action, Action1, which redirects to another action, Action2, via `RedirectToAction`. This results in an HTTP 302 response. The response appears to be cached somewhere because subsequent calls to Action1 never hit the server. I have tried the following:

1. Set the output cache in the Web.config to disabled.
2. Cleared my browser's (Chrome and IE9) cache.
3. Appended a random number to the request for Action1.
4. Changed what Action1 does to see if it would trigger the cache to die.
5. Disabled my network connection thinking that somehow my localhost requests were being cached in a router or something.

No matter what I do, it seems that there is a layer of caching somewhere that still exists. I am running the application in IIS 7.5 locally on my laptop. I am accessing it from the same machine. My only final thought is that IIS is caching the redirection somewhere - but I can't figure out where that might be. Th only other thing that may be worth mentioning is that I am posting the request by creating a form on the fly and submitting it using jQuery.

Here are the request headers when I request Action1:

```
POST /Test/Action1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/Test
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: CartID=2637139; ASP.NET_SessionId=njto1i55dsbfsib5x2vpin55; siteuidut=6750fc9eda6c479db11ce10328a595ec; UserID=1; .ASPXAUTH=0:6172Tz9ggmhlHKcOJE+Jmg==
```

Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Test/Action2
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2012 00:42:59 GMT
Content-Length: 140
```

Comment: you can try disabling cache by doing something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11574149/1279541)